# How to deduplicate a merged array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to merge two arrays which have some duplicated values into one array which has no duplicates. I am using `concat` but the result is all value.

```
var a = [1,2,2];
var b = [1,2,3,3];
var c = a.concat(b);
console.log(c);
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge them into a Set, and turn that set back into an array:

```js
var a = [1,2,2];
var b = [1,2,3,3];
var c = [...new Set([...a, ...b])];
console.log(c);
```

You can also use `concat` and `Array.from` as an alternative to spread syntax if necessary:

```js
var a = [1,2,2];
var b = [1,2,3,3];
var c = Array.from(new Set(a.concat(b)));
console.log(c);
```

Comment: you beat me  by seconds haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Add both of them to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which is a data structure that ignores duplicates.